# How to pattern match a Box to get a struct's attribute?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to access an attribute of a boxed struct inside an enum but I can't figure out how to pattern-match with `std::boxed::Box`

```
enum ArithExp {
    Sum {
        lhs: Box<ArithExp>,
        rhs: Box<ArithExp>,
    },
    Mul {
        lhs: Box<ArithExp>,
        rhs: Box<ArithExp>,
    },
    Num {
        value: f64,
    },
}

fn num(value: f64) -> std::boxed::Box<ArithExp> {
    Box::new(ArithExp::Num { value })
}

let mut number = num(1.0);
match number {
    ArithExp::Num { value } => println!("VALUE = {}", value),
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:9
   |
22 |         ArithExp::Num { value } => println!("VALUE = {}", value),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::boxed::Box`, found enum `main::ArithExp`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::boxed::Box<main::ArithExp>`
              found type `main::ArithExp`
```

What is the correct way of accessing the attribute?

Comment: @ljedrz I think this is a bit different. The linked question is specifically about pattern matching the box itself. This is more about matching the contents of the box.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to dereference the boxed value so that you can access what's inside the box:

```
match *number {
    ArithExp::Num { value } => println!("VALUE = {}", value),
    _ => (),
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=66766b9141fee1659e77111d4b703c79&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue (also for an expression tree `struct`) but when I deference the box valued I get a different compiler error because the variable I'm pattern matching against is behind a shared reference. For example, I'm having to `match **expr { ... }` (one dereference for the reference, and the other for unboxing the value). The compiler suggests that I need to implement the `Copy` trait - is this the only way around this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to move the items in the `Box` you can take a reference to the contents and match on that instead of just dereferencing:

```rust
match &*number {
    ArithExp::Num { value } => println!("VALUE = {}", value),
    _ => (),
}
```

This only gives you references to the contents, but often that's all you need.