# How to match value of <T> in Box<T> that is attribute of a Struct?

Tags: rust, dereference

I am trying to parse a simple query using [sqlparser](https://docs.rs/sqlparser/0.12.0/sqlparser/index.html) crate and I got stuck on **BinaryOp** struct that is value of [Expr enum](https://docs.rs/sqlparser/0.12.0/sqlparser/ast/enum.Expr.html) and the struct itself contains [Expr enum](https://docs.rs/sqlparser/0.12.0/sqlparser/ast/enum.Expr.html).

I am able to print output by matching:

`sqlparser::ast::Expr::BinaryOp{left:a , op: b , right: c} => println!("{:?}",a)`

But when I try to get Expr from it, it errors with following:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:41:57
   |
38 | ...                   BinaryOp{left:a , op: b , right: c} => match *a {
   |                                                                    --
   |                                                                    |
   |                                                                    this expression has type `Box<Expr>`
   |                                                                    help: consider dereferencing the boxed value: `**a`
...
41 | ...                       sqlparser::ast::Expr::CompoundIdentifier(w) => {},
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found enum `Expr`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Box<Expr>`
                found enum `Expr`
```

I assume it is the problem with dereference, however I am unable to resolve it even if I added the dereference (*a).

Complete code here:

```
use sqlparser::dialect::GenericDialect;
use sqlparser::parser::Parser;
use sqlparser::ast::Statement::Query;
use sqlparser::ast::SetExpr;
use sqlparser::ast::Expr::BinaryOp;



fn main() {
    let dialect = GenericDialect {}; // or AnsiDialect

    let sql = "SELECT a,b FROM table_1 T1 left join table_2 T2 on T1.z = T2.z";

    let ast = &Parser::parse_sql(&dialect, sql).unwrap()[0];

    if let Query(x) = ast {
        match &x.body {
            SetExpr::Select(s) => {let projection = &s.projection;
                                   let from = &s.from;
                                   //let group = &s.group_by;

                                   for p in projection {
                                       if let sqlparser::ast::SelectItem::UnnamedExpr(i) = p {
                                           match i {
                                                sqlparser::ast::Expr::Identifier(r) => println!("{:?}", r.value),
                                                _ => {},
                                           };
                                       }
                                   }

                                   for f in from {
                                       //println!("{:?}",f.relation);
                                       for j in &f.joins {
                                           match &j.join_operator {
                                            sqlparser::ast::JoinOperator::Inner(inj) => println!("inner join {:?}",inj),
                                            sqlparser::ast::JoinOperator::LeftOuter(lfj) => match lfj {
                                                sqlparser::ast::JoinConstraint::On(on) => match on {
                                                    BinaryOp{left:a , op: b , right: c} => match *a {
                                                    
                                                        
                                                        sqlparser::ast::Expr::CompoundIdentifier(w) => {},

                                                        _ => {}
                                                    },
                                                _ => {}
                                                },
                                                _ => {}
                                            },
                                            _ => {}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
            },                      
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

How it should be done to get the boxed value from BinaryOp struct?

Thank you.

Comment: **Style comment:** aligning code the way you have is creating a huge amount of indentation that makes your code unnecessarily hard to read. At this line: `SetExpr::Select(s) => {` you may wish to skip to the next line and indent the rest the standard 4 spaces you've used elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `a` has type `&Box<Expr>`, so when you dereference it, `*a`, it only removes the reference leaving just `Box<Expr>`. You unfortunately cannot do pattern matching on values in a `Box` (see [How to pattern match a Box to get a struct's attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398060/how-to-pattern-match-a-box-to-get-a-structs-attribute)), so you have to dereference it *again* to get an `Expr`:

```
match **a {
```

However, then the match arm will try to *move* the variable `w` out of `**a`, which is not allowed since it is behind a shared reference.

You can either avoid moving entirely by referencing the `Expr` via `&**a` or by binding to `ref w` instead of just `w`. If this starts looking like too much symbol soup for you, another option is to use `a.as_ref()` (via the [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait).

Comment: This is entirely correct, however I would recommend changing `&**a` to `a.as_ref()`. The result is the same (see it's implementation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1755-1759), however I would argue the latter is more readable.

Comment: @PossiblyAShrub thanks for that suggestion! I've changed my recommendation to use that instead of `Deref`.